# How to reset numpy.zeros()

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to make a connect 4 board in the terminal using numpy.zeros

The main problem is that my reset function resets the board but on the next move it goes back

I followed this tutorial: https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/connect-four-game

My Reset Function:

```
def create_board():
    board = np.zeros((ROW_COUNT,COLUMN_COUNT))
    return board
```

The inital call to make the empty board

```
board = create_board()
```

I can interact with that easily, but when I call the create_board() function, it resets then reverts after the next move.

```
    #Checks For a winner
    if winning_move(board, 1):
        create_board()
```

Before reseting the terminal prints this:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]]
```

After calling the function the terminal print this:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

but when I make a move(the new 2), it prints the previous things with the new move and adds to that:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 0. 1. 0.]]
```

I tracked down the issue to the way I reset but im new at using numpy and I don't know if im resetting it correctly. Please let me know if you would like more information that I did not provide. Thanks!

Comment: what you're describing doesn't make much sense. Check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You say you've tracked the issue to the way you reset, but don't provide the code for `reset()`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You likely make a copy of the board in `reset` or assign to a local variable.

No need for a function, just set all values to 0:

```
board[:] = 0
```